# Run screen splitted and specify commands for each windows?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

Ubuntu 12.04, I would like to run gnu-screen already splitted in two regions and with certain commands in it, I have [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218091/execute-command-for-all-windows-in-the-screen) that in new version of screen there are `-Q` argument, but I still dont get how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Please expand your question to include your environment, your goal and what you've tried already.

Comment: @Raystafarian done:)